# Nested JSON, string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, parsing

I've got JSON nested multiple times and my code results in

> string indices must be integers

I think I'm missing another step to get the deeply nested JSON data, not sure what I'm doing wrong!

```
json_obj = response.json()
for data in json_obj["data"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO engagementscores (mean) VALUES (%s)",
                   (data['scores']["mean"],))
```

JSON Output

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "engagement_overviews",
    "id": "company_8341",
    "attributes": {
      "scores": {
        "mean": 8.627906976744185,
        "variance": 2.2392026578073088,
        "size": 43,
        "nps": {
          "promoters": 25,
          "passives": 14,
          "detractors": 4,
          "score": 48.83720930232558
        },
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through a dictionary. `data` will be the next *key* in the dict in each loop iteration. Since there appears to be only one top level key, `data` is going to be `"data"`.

You don't need the loop.

```
data = response.json()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO engagementscores (mean) VALUES (%s)',
               (data['data']['attributes']['scores']['mean'],))
```